# Enable drag and drop UITableViewCell without "setEditing:" method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to enable drag and drop UITableViewCell to swap them. It's not a problem, but i want to do it without "setEditing:" method. I want to swap cells before user drag cell using something like longGestureAction and drop it in another place, but without disabling selectRow method, and without show side icons.

I don't want something like this:

[1img http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10739464/stackoverflow/bad.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10739464/stackoverflow/bad.png)

I want something like this /with possibility to drag and drop of course/:

[2img http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10739464/stackoverflow/good.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10739464/stackoverflow/good.png)

Oh, I need to enable drag and drop like in "Clear" to-do app.

Comment: Let's talk in english, so that other users on Stack Overflow can understand our conversation :) Yes I think I found a solution. I'll post my answer in several minutes

Answer (score 6):

You can easily acheive this efect **using** `-setEditing:`. You just have to assign some properties of your `UITableViewCells`:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = ...;

    cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
    cell.showsReorderControl = NO;

    return cell;

}
```

Just make sure you call `-setEditing:` in `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I searched a little bit on the web and found this: [JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtgesturebasedtableviewdemo). It's ClearApp-based and it's very impressive. You can take a look how it's done and apply some solutions in you app :)

---

**EDIT #2:** If you want to enable selection during editing, just set this property of tableView:

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Of course I can reorder cells, but I can't select it.

Comment: @edit: Maybe `tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES` will work for you?

Comment: it based on gestures, I'll try to implement it to my app :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: And how about `allowsSelectionDuringEditing`?

Comment: tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing works almost perfectly, but I still have icon on the right side, and I can't drag cell on the entire width :/

Comment: So, I think it cannot be done easily using `UITableView` natural methods. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Of course, thanks for your time and help :) I'll try with JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :  https://github.com/ice3-software/i3-dragndrop
and this stack over flow link : [drag and drop from uitableviewcell to uiimage view in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404948/drag-and-drop-from-uitableviewcell-to-uiimage-view-in-ios)

(For the above mentioned library you can use try using 1st example.)

I would have liked it more to post this as comment..but, I don't have enough reputation.

Hope it helps someone.